# Colab: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pandas==1.4.1

Tags: pandas, pip

In Colab notebook, I did:

```
!pip install pandas==1.4.1
```

but returned:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pandas==1.4.1 (from versions: 0.1, 0.2, 0.3.0, 0.4.0, 0.4.1, 0.4.2, 0.4.3, 0.5.0, 0.6.0, 0.6.1, 0.7.0, 0.7.1, 0.7.2, 0.7.3, 0.8.0, 0.8.1, 0.9.0, 0.9.1, 0.10.0, 0.10.1, 0.11.0, 0.12.0, 0.13.0, 0.13.1, 0.14.0, 0.14.1, 0.15.0, 0.15.1, 0.15.2, 0.16.0, 0.16.1, 0.16.2, 0.17.0, 0.17.1, 0.18.0, 0.18.1, 0.19.0, 0.19.1, 0.19.2, 0.20.0, 0.20.1, 0.20.2, 0.20.3, 0.21.0, 0.21.1, 0.22.0, 0.23.0, 0.23.1, 0.23.2, 0.23.3, 0.23.4, 0.24.0, 0.24.1, 0.24.2, 0.25.0, 0.25.1, 0.25.2, 0.25.3, 1.0.0, 1.0.1, 1.0.2, 1.0.3, 1.0.4, 1.0.5, 1.1.0, 1.1.1, 1.1.2, 1.1.3, 1.1.4, 1.1.5, 1.2.0, 1.2.1, 1.2.2, 1.2.3, 1.2.4, 1.2.5, 1.3.0, 1.3.1, 1.3.2, 1.3.3, 1.3.4, 1.3.5)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for pandas==1.4.1
```

Any idea how to upgrade to `pandas==1.4.1` in colab?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`pandas` 1.4+ [requires](https://pypi.org/project/pandas/1.4.0/) Python >= 3.8. From the list of available versions I can guess you use Python 3.7 or lower.

Upgrade Python or use lower version of pandas. Just `pip install pandas` should find compatible version.